# How do I use whitespaces in expressions and statements according to conventions?

Tags: python, coding-style, conventions

I tried to submit this code:

```
temperature = input("enter a tempereture as you wish: ")
convertion = int(temperature[:-1])
if temperature[-1] == "C":
    convertion = int((9 * convertion) / 5 + 32)
    temperature = str(convertion) + "F"
elif temperature[-1] == "F":
    convertion = int((5 * convertion) / 9 - 160/9)
    temperature = str(convertion) + "C"
print(temperature)
```

When I did so, I was told my writing wasn't following the conventions. I read https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements, and still couldn't understand my mistake. Where was I wrong?

Comment: Who said that it doesn't follow conventions?

Comment: I submit my codes to an Auto Feedback platform

Comment: Does the code executes as expected? If not, can you post the error please

Comment: What you have written is fine, may be add some newlines between conditional blocks. "Although practicality beats purity." ~ *Zen of Python*.

Comment: There is no error and the code executes just fine surprisingly

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be here, at the end of the line :

```
convertion = int((5 * convertion) / 9 - 160/9)
```

You can try :

```
convertion = int((5 * convertion) / 9 - 160 / 9)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
temperature = input("enter a temperature as you wish: ")

conversion = int(temperature[:-1])

if temperature[-1] == "C":

    conversion = int((9 * conversion) / 5 + 32)

    temperature = str(conversion) + "F"

elif temperature[-1] == "F":

    conversion = int((5 * conversion) / 9 - 160 / 9)

    temperature = str(conversion) + "C"

print(temperature)
```

Can you try with the above code. Didn't change much though!!